# How to bind data from .ts file of one page to html of another page

Tags: angular, data-binding

I am trying to implement the binding concept in Angular.I have the below code in
 **PageOne.ts**

```
this.navCtrl.push("PageTwo",{
      paramType: params,

    })
```

**PageTwo.html**:

```
<span>{{paramType}}</span>
```

I am trying to access the paramType in another page template.
But the data is not getting passed successfully.

Comment: Obviously the code you provided is insufficient to understand hat's the issue here. Please at least provide how you try to access the parameters in the `PageTwo` component

Comment: I am not worried about PageTwo.ts . I am looking for a way to bind to PageTwo.html . <span>{{paramType}}</span>                                                 This is what I have inside PageTwo.html . But the data is not getting passed .

Comment: You just posted the same code. What is inside `PageTwo.ts`?

Comment: I am worried about `PageTwo.ts`, as it will show exactly *how* you try to access the data. Can you please just post the code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There are numerous ways to pass data from one component (.ts file) to another. The correct way really depends on how your code is set up. Is Page Two a child of Page One? (Meaning that it is embedded in it's html?) Are you navigating between two sibling components? If you could provide a little more code we could provide more specific guidance.

Comment: In my case, both are sibling components,my pageTwo.ts looks like this,ionViewDidLoad() {
   
    this.paramType = this.navParams.get('paramType');
  }                                                                                                                           I am getting value inside this.paramType. But if i bind that to html like {{paramType}} this doesnt work..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass data between Components are Services.
read more here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

But in order to be able to help you we need more information about your project and your code!